# How to check positive definiteness of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functions

Is there a general criterion for checking if a given function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is positive definite?

Comment: If the function is continuous then exists some $\beta>0$ such that $f(x,x)\ge \beta|x|^2$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: My function has is continuous except at $\mathbf{0}$ where it goes to $+\infty$. Will the criteria still hold?

Comment: The kernel $f(x_1, x_2)=\exp (-(x_1-x_2)^2)$ is a P.D. function, but it violates your test.

Comment: The above definition is in the context of bilinear functions. I dont know the general definition of "positive definiteness".

Comment: A symmetric function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called positive definite (P.D.) if $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j f(x_i, x_j) \geq 0$$ holds for any $n$, $x_i$'s and $c_i$'s.